# cURL não esta funcionando no meu localhost

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho um codigo em PHP para listar um estoque no OLX.

Em produção ele funciona perfeitamente.

no local curl não esta funcionando de jeito nenhum.

```
$url = 'https://apps.olx.com.br/autoupload/published';
$ch = curl_init($url);
$payload = json_encode(array('access_token' => $pacote['token']));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

sim, no phpinfo info tem o curl executando:

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.24.0
```

o comando `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` tem a seguinte saída.

```
Array ( [url] => https://apps.olx.com.br/autoupload/published [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.016 [namelookup_time] => 0.016 [connect_time] => 0.016 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => 54.233.83.19 [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 10.25.61.90 [local_port] => 65055 [redirect_url] => )
```

o codigo `$data = curl_exec($ch);` retorna false.

Repetindo esse código em produção retorna uma lista perfeitamente.
Estou usando windows 10. *php 5.4.45*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `[http_code] => 0` indica que é um erro interno do cURL, provavelmente está relacionado:

- Problema no TLS/SSL:

  - Não possui o OpenSSL instalado (ou desatualizado);
  - Não definiu as *certificate authorities* confiáveis (não tem um CABundle);
- Problema no DNS:

  - Não definiu um DNS e não há um definido por padrão.

Existem outros problemas, mas isso não foi incluído em sua resposta, estas são as mais comuns.

---

A solução para o TLS/SSL pode ser instalar um OpenSSL (ou habilita-lo) e definir um CABundle. Desligar o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` pode ser uma opção, mas isto lhe deixa vulnerável a MITM.

A melhor opção é ir em https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html (ou obter o certificado do autoridade que emitiu o certificado do site especifico) e então especificar:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'caminho/para/cacert.pem');
```

Já para o DNS pode optar por usar o DoH (DNS-over-HTTPS), nas versões mais recentes do Curl. Honestamente, não sei se o PHP já suporta isso (se não, talvez daqui à alguns anos isso será uma solução válida).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DOH_URL, 'https://1.1.1.1/dns-query');
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz seguinte codigo:

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:
```

application/json;charset=UTF-8'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);= curl_exec($ch);
            print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
            $response = curl_error($ch);
            echo stripslashes($response);
            curl_close($ch);`insira o código aqui`

Resultado echo striplashes($response) foi

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Ou Seja é so configurar SSL ou tentar sem ele.